# Unity can't import System.Data.dll

Tags: sql-server, unity-game-engine, dllimport

I'm using Unity 2018.4.5f1 and I'm trying to connect to SQL Server.

I followed many online instructions and drag **System.Data.dll** from `D:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0` to the assets.

And then it showed me the following error messages:

[image]

I then go online searching for solutions and drag the `dll` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Unity Subset v3.5` instead to no avail!

I moved the `dll` in and out of the `plugin` folder, no luck!

I checked the `Scripting Runtime Version` and `Api Compatibility Level`, it's `.NET 4.x Equivalent` and `.NET Standard 2.0` as the online documents instructed.

I even downgrade my VS from 2019 to 2017!

All for nothing!

Please, I really had tried very hard and still unable to solve this problem!

Could somebody please be so kind and teach me how to fix it, please!

Much much appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you compiling as IL2PP? Normally you need the mono one, and to have set the runtime versions, although I thought it was both to 4.. Due to some firewalls I ended up having to make a webservice as some bright spark decided to turn off sql through the firewall.. as well as that way you dont need access to all insundry to your db server leaving it more open to attacks

Comment: I didn't compile it as anything. The error message appeared right after I drag the dll into the assets!

Comment: the version of visual studio wont change anything, so you can stay with 2019.    Under the compiler what does it actually say is the problem? as mine says multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported..

Comment: I don't really know what the problem is! All I did is drag the dll into the assets in Unity and it showed me the error message as my picture showed! It will show me the same error even if it's a brand new project! As long as I drag the dll into the assets, the error appeared!!!

Comment: Ok but in the console where you see the error, click on it, and in the bottom part that window are the details of what actually its whining about

Comment: It seems like 2018.4.5f1 don't need to import `System.Data.dll`. The package come with it! But the build-in version seems doesn't include any SqlClient packages, so now how am I suppose to connect to the SQL Server!?

Comment: The same way you do in any c# code..  You may need to copy the client dll in :P